# Как получить имя учетной записи asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core

Для авторизации использую Windows authentication.
Использую `@Context.User.Identity.Name` получаю имя домена и логин (domen/Vpupkin), а надо, что бы выводило имя учетной записи - Василий Пупкин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увы, пока никак.

Для этого в asp.net core нет поддержки для System.DirectoryServices.

Обещали сделать поддержку в core 2.0 - но до сих пор не реализовано.

Когда сделают - можно будет писать что-то в духе:

```
var userNameFull = this.User.Identity.Name; // example: domain\AK

var domain = userNameFull.Split('\\').First();
var accountName = userNameFull.Split('\\').Last();

using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}"))
{
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
    {
        searcher.Filter = $"(sAMAccountName={name})";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
        var searchResult = searcher.FindOne();

        if (searchResult != null && searchResult.Properties.Contains("displayName"))
        {
            var displayName = searchResult.Properties["displayName"][0];
        }
        else
        {
            // user not found
        }
    }
}
```

Ссылки по теме:

- [.NET Core LDAP](https://long2know.com/2017/06/net-core-ldap/)
- [Support for System.DirectoryServices for Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089)
- [How to get Active Directory current user Display Name in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39965898/5752652)