# ASP.NET.MVC 5 Автоматизация распределения прав в проекте(контроллере) с использованием Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

не могли бы помочь с кодом либо поделиться полезной ссылкой по данному вопросу.
Задача следующая, у меня в основной таблице где лежат данные есть колонка "Branch"
В этой колонке 25 названий ко каждому из названий, я создам(л) 25 ссылок где у пользователя будет выбор. Загвоздка в том что к каждой ссылке, я собираюсь назначить доступ определенной группе из ActiveDirectory. Я могу создать еще 24 таких же контроллеров и осуществить задуманное, но это будет не правильно.

Мой контроллер следующий

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestNew(string branchname)
    {
        // check stuff like permissions
        var db = new MovieContext();
        var model = new Model();


        var students = db.Student
            .Where(x => x.BranchName == branchname)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.BranchName, x.Name, x.Currency, x.NoCart, x.NoAccount })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                BranchName = x.FirstOrDefault().BranchName,
                Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                A_Status = x.Max(p => p.A_Status),
                Currency = x.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                NoCart = x.FirstOrDefault().NoCart,
                NoAccount = x.FirstOrDefault().NoAccount
            }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in students)
        {
            model.Students.Add(new Student
            {
                A_Status = item.A_Status,
                BranchName = item.BranchName,
                Name = item.Name,
                NoAccount = item.NoAccount,
                NoCart = item.NoCart,
                Currency = item.Currency

            });
        }
        return View(model);
```

Comment: Почему вы не хотите внутри вашего метода дёрнуть LDAP на предмет нужной вам информации и в зависимости от ответа отдать либо HTTP 403, либо страницу? В [core ещё не подвезли ldap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/806325/213987), но из классического asp.net mvc должно без проблем сработать.

Comment: То есть ?) как это реализовать

Comment: Он кстати итак дергает с ActiveDirectory

Comment: Если я укажу группу из AD то доступ применится к указанному контроллеру

Comment: Указывайте минимальную группу из AD (Например, Users), остальные группы проверяйте из кода.

Comment: А этот метод как называется когда ты дописываешь в URL адресе

Comment: (string branchname) localhost/testnew/Some_branch_1